# Inserting term frequency value to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tf-idf

```
corpus = [
 'this is the first document',
 'this document is the second document',
 'and this is the third one',
 'is this the first document',]

def computeTF(corpus):
tfDict={}
for row in range(0,len(corpus)):
    number_of_words=dict(Counter(corpus[row].split()))
    for word,count in number_of_words.items():
        tfDict[word]=count/len(corpus[row].split())
return tfDict

tfValue = computeTF(corpus)
print(tfValue)
```

I am calculating term frequency for each words in the corpus. After calculating all the values i am adding those values to tfDict and returning it. But value is not getting returned properly for each word. What exactly is going wrong?

Current value {'this': 0.2, 'is': 0.2, 'the': 0.2, 'first': 0.2, 'document': 0.2, 'second': 0.16666666666666666, 'and': 0.16666666666666666, 'third': 0.16666666666666666, 'one': 0.16666666666666666}

Expected value:-
{'this': 0.2, 'is': 0.2, 'the': 0.2, 'first': 0.2,'document':0.2},
{'this':0.16,'document':0.33,'is':0.16,'the':0.16,'second':0.16,'document':0.33},
{'and':0.16,'this',:0.16,'is':0.16,'the':0.16,'third':0.16,'one':0.16},{'is':0.2,'this':0.2,'the':0.2,'first':0.2,'document':0.2}

Comment: Post the value you expected and value you are currently getting.

Comment: I have added the expected and actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, your definition of dictionary in the loop would reassign the TF-value of the words so you need to create a counter for every document.

Try the code below:

```
def computeTF(corpus):
    tfDict = {}
    bowCount=0
    Document = 0
    #import ipdb ; ipdb.set_trace()
    for row in range(0,len(corpus)):
        number_of_words=dict(Counter(corpus[row].split()))
        #print(number_of_words)
        for word,count in number_of_words.items():
            tfDict["%s in Corpus-%s"%(word,Document)]=count/len(corpus[row].split())
        Document += 1
    return tfDict

tfValue = computeTF(corpus)
print(tfValue)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you need this code

```
corpus = [
    'this is the first document',
    'this document is the second document',
    'and this is the third one',
    'is this the first document', ]

def computeTF(corpus):
    tfDict = {}
    for line in corpus:
        tfDict[line] = {}
        line_words = line.split()
        for word in line_words:
            tfDict[line][word] = line_words.count(word)/len(line_words)
    return tfDict

print(computeTF(corpus))
```

Comment: Could you pls check what is wrong with my code. Where is the issue?

Comment: First of all, I don't know your Counter function so I couldn't execute your code. But it is not necessary to assign another dictionary to keep counters. After that, the most fatal logic error is at your `tfDict[word]=count/len(corpus[row].split())` line. For example, every line includes _this_ but you always keep the last value. You should use a nested dictionary to separate them. Finally, think simple, python is a suitable language for this.